# curl json object null for some reason

Tags: php, json, curl, netbeans, wampserver

Im using netbeans 8.0.2 with wampserver 3.0.0 to run php. So far so good untill now.

When trying to make a curl request to bungie's API that returns a JSON object, the object received is null.
The thing is, I tried running the same code in http://phpfiddle.org/ and it actually works, so now i dont know whats the problem.

PHP CODE:

```
    $apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.bungie.net/platform/destiny/{myplatform}/Stats/GetMembershipIdByDisplayName/{mygamertag}/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-API-Key: ' . $apiKey));
    $json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    echo $json->Response;
```

Curl is enabled, php works fine so im clueless right now since i dont know what is the problem.

The error i get is "Trying to get property of non-object" in the echo command.

Comment: Please show the output of `curl_exec($ch)` (ie before you attempt to decode it as JSON). It's possible there's some error that's creeping in there and preventing the JSON library from parsing it.

Comment: curl_exec($ch) is null.                                                                                  Anyway i dont think its a coding error since it works here http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: Did you use `var_dump()` to test the return value of `curl_exec`? It shouldn't return NULL, it should return either the result or FALSE, so NULL suggests something odd going on.

Comment: Yep, my bad, this is what happens when i use var_dump(curl_exec($ch)) : D:\Programs\wamp64\www\pls\index.php:20:boolean false

Comment: Awesome. At least we know where the issue is now - cURL is having trouble connecting for some reason. Try printing out the return from `curl_error($ch)` after your code - this should give you a human readable description of what went wrong.

Comment: Alright, thats whats going on then : D:\Programs\wamp64\www\pls\index.php:22:string 'SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate'

Comment: Ah, this is a relatively common issue with running your own server: as you're connecting over HTTPS, cURL is trying to verify the site's certificate. If this is a testing server setup that you've got, you can disable this check with `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)`.

Comment: OMG it works!! U are the best, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `var_dump`:

```
var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

or `print`, for example (from doc):

```
$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345
```

or echo similar as print...

Comment: This is what happens when i use var_dump(json_decode(curl_exec($ch))) : D:\Programs\wamp64\www\pls\index.php:21:null . And if i use print i get the same error than i get from echo.

Comment: when you print or echo you should use neme of variable like in my example

Comment: `echo curl_exec($ch)` before decode, then you see direct output, probably you have an error...